# Find basis and dimension of a subspace

Tags: matrices, span

Problem: Let V be the subspace of all 2x2 matrices over R, and W the subspace spanned by:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -5 \\
-4 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -4 \\
-5 & 7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -7 \\
-5 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Q: Find a basis and the dimension of W.

What I've done so far:

-I'll refer to the matrices as W1, W2, W3 and W4 (top-down). I've noticed so far that W3 = W1 + W2, does that means that span(W1,W2,W3,W4) = span(W1,W2,W3) ?

I know that a way to find a basis is by reducing a matrix of coefficients to a echelon form, but how do I represent those matrices in a coefficients matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider each matrix to be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

[image]

The only pivots are in the first two columns, so the first two matrices are linearly independent and form a basis for the subspace. The last two are linear combinations of the first. Notice that $M_3=M_1+M_2$, and $M_4=\frac{4}{3} M_1-\frac{1}{3}M_2$

Comment: Why one can consider each matrix to be a vector?

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, you should look for the maximum set of linearly independent matrices.

For example, if $M_1$,$ M_2$, and $M_4$ are linearly independent, but $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_3$ and $M_4$ are not, then the maximum set of linearly independent matrices are $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_4$, then this set is a basis of the subspace W. So now you have a basis, just count the elements and you have the dimension.

I hope this may help.

Comment: According to your answer, and considering that I've already checked that M1, M2 and M4 are  linearly independent - in this problem, only M3 can be written as linear combination of the other matrices, but M1, M2 and M4 can only admit the trivial solution - I can say that a basis for W is the set formed by M1, M2 and M4?

Comment: That's right! The theorem says that if you have a maximum set of linearly independent vectors, then this set is a basis.

Comment: @woz $M_4$ is a linear combination of $M_1$ and $M_2$

Comment: @reluctantmathematician thanks! In fact I just checked and noticed a mistake!